# ドットインストールでタスクappをrailsでのつまづき

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dotinstall

NoMethodError in TasksController#create
undefined method `tasks' for nil:NilClass

このようなエラーが出ました。
どなたかヒントをくださると助かります。

アバウトな質問でごめんなさい。

Comment: アバウトな質問でごめんなさいと思っておられるなら，もう少し具体的にされてはどうでしょうか．少なくとも何をしようとして何をしたのかくらいは書くのにそれほど難しくないと思います．

Answer (score 1):

エラーの意味は
TasksControllerという変数のcreateというメソッドを使おうとしたけどTasksControllerの現在の値であるnil:NilClassにはそのようなメソッドはありません。
ということですね。
TasksControllerの生成が失敗しているのでそれを作ったところまで遡って原因を探す必要があります。
単純に変数名のタイプミスのことも多いですが。